# Pre-Amplifier Question

Tags: audio, active-filter, passive-filter

back at it again with a problem that I am stuck on and need some clear explanation of.

1/2: I was wondering How those Bass controls work, for example the ones in the car you allow to change the bass from -10 to 0 to 10 and the bass would increase to barely hearing the drums. Is this due to a gain change or a Fc(Cut off frequency) change?

2/2 I been having a problem on a filter, and I am sure I am over thinking it, however in the picture below using an Input source of 1.92Vpk @ 1kHz. The Fc of the High pass filter is ~250Hz however the 1kHz is not at 0dB which means I am losing some sound on this common frequency in audio which isn't good. I was wondering to over come this problem would a higher order filter would work? Essentially making the roll off more sharper ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. Frequency-dependent gain -- bass means "low f" so here a bass control will provide non-zero dB gain at low freq, either + or -, moving back towards flat gain at higher f. 2. Higher order filter is a way. 3. You want +/- dB gain at low frequency since you are talking about bass control, even if the flat gain part is just 0 dB. You also want steep cutoff for some reason at the high end, it seems.  Answering your question is difficult because of the conflation of ideas in it, so I think as it is that it would require a too-long answer for me to consider.

Comment: What is the purpose of this filter? You clearly don’t need gain  and driving 620 Ohms is already possible. Define all parameters , load , power and spectrum and anything else that matters (Application)

Comment: Its a pre amplifier, Just to control the input signal's bass and volume control. Its going into a power amplifier so this pre amp wont see the load.

Comment: Nothing you have posted is any kind of an amplifier.  You have posted a couple of examples of simple single pole filters RC filters.  No gain to be had there.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, sorry about that what I meant is I am going to use this low pass filter in a pre amplifier. This is getting out of topic. The problem is stated as how to overcome the Fc curve and what does it mean to control bass? is it a gain increase / decrease or is it a FC shift

Comment: it means gain decrease/increase. However, how much a frequency is attenuated is related to how far it is from the cutoff frequency (in non-ideal filters), so that also matters

Comment: Bass control is BOTH + and -. You can boost bass or you can diminish it. That, plus treble control, would be a "first order" (beginner's) approach to a (shelving) equalizer, with a graphic or parametric equalizer just having lots more bands and control modes.

Comment: I see, wouldnt it be better to change the FC? as if you increase the gain of the bass lines arent you more risk for clipping at the power amplifier stages? @FrancoVS

Comment: Might go see: [EQ types](http://www.ovnilab.com/articles/eqtypes.shtml).

Comment: Also, here is the kind of specification you might want to provide -- graphically. These images are for shelving equalization (bass ***and*** treble), but they get the idea across for bass, too. An [ideal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru2WY.gif) and a more [realistic image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnpf2.jpg) to examine. Note that you need to specify the max and min (or +dB and -dB) gain figures for bass, as well as the filter slope. And if you compare the non-ideal with the ideal versions, you'll another behavior that you may want to at least be aware of, if not specify.

Comment: Thats hard to say as isn't limited by the power stage amplifier cause I obviously dont want it clipping.

Comment: @Pllsz Then you ALSO appear to want companding (variable gain based upon signal level and frequency and your bass boost/cut setting.) Or, perhaps you want to lower the gain on the higher frequencies, when the bass is boosted.

Comment: Yes, thats later in the works right now I am trying to understand bass boost and bass cut is from changing the gain of the lower frequencies.

and asking if higher order filters would fix the problem that I am having above: The Fc =250hz however 1kHz isnt at 0dB having a sharper roll off will fix this?

Comment: @Pllsz Why does the very slight difference at 4*Fc, -0.26dB, vs 0dB, matter? These are all questions you should completely answer in your question. If -0.26dB at 4 Fc matters to you, then you must say why it does. You should detail what you care about and why you care about it and WHERE you care about it.

Comment: You're right it doesnt matter but for me it does

1. This is a personal project and I would like to do everything to the best I can, so if I can improve that -0.26dB I would..

2. This project I am doing will later then be used in a portfolio so anything I can used to talk about theory and what not or place where I improved something can be benificial

3. and just to prove myself if that makes sense.

4. and just for knowledge I guess

Comment: @Pllsz So, you are looking for a sweeping overview education supplemented by specific concrete cases to illustrate the application of general theory. This isn't just a filter, though you appear to want a good education on filters too. It's also the case that if you are *boosting* the bass, that you instead need to *cut* the higher frequencies and leave the bass unboosted and uncut. So it's non-trivial. Do you have any books on the topic?

Comment: Well then, I do not. I am just asking simple questions. I can take care of the rest. I am asking if its a GAIN increase or Fc Shift thats all. No need to go into that nice well spoken sentence lol

Comment: @Pllsz You specifically state that you don't want to cause clipping. That sounds simple to you. But given boost and cut, that does NOT sound like a simple question to me. I think we leave it here, then. Someone else can wade through this and figure out what you actually do need here. I'm honestly confused at this point and must accept that my confusion isn't being improved at this point. So I'll let my betters have at it.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not being very clear here. Do you want a preamp circuit or a equalizer circuit? What is your load?

1. C1 generally appears in these circuits as a bypass capacitor, not some sort of bass control capacitor. You generally don't want it to attenuate frequencies you want to reproduce.
2. First pick which frequencies you want and which ones you want to attenuate, and by how much. Then figure out the order of the filter you need. Assuming you just want some half-assed bass attenuation... you can change your filter's cutoff frequency down by increasing R1. My first instinct would be to try a 30k pot in series with that 620R resistor and see what the bode plot yields you. Be aware that you can't make the attenuation steeper with that circuit - for that you need a higher order filter.
3. Yes. It should be trivial to reduce the gain in circuits involving op-amps. The easiest way is to use a voltage divider at the input.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that once again...

Anyways I want a pre amp circuit with the functionality to control the bass frequencies (You can hear more bass and switch it to less bass).

1. What? Yeah its a typical first order High pass filter, I was planning to use a potentiometer on the resistor there from 620ohms to 8.2k so I can control the FC from 20Hz to 250Hz

2. 20Hz to 250Hz is the bass frequencies I want to control

3. Sorry I am lost here? Reduce the gain? I want the gains to be constant within my band pass? 20Hz to 250Hz.

Comment: You complained some butterworth circuit has too high of a gain. You can reduce it easily for all frequencies with a voltage divider if that's a problem

Comment: I did, however it drastically changed the Fc.

Comment: @Pllsz If you are using passive filters, of course adding a load will change the response Fc. I'd assumed you were thinking of active filters, but now see that you've added passive schematics. So, I guess that's what you are doing?

Comment: No load! The butterworth I used was an active filter so the input and output were isolated from each other. I meant I made the NFB to a voltage follower.

Comment: I think everyone is over thinking it to be honest, I am just wondering what eq are adjusting the bass and you hear harder bass is it from increasing the gain of the lower frequencies or is they they're shifting the Fc lower.

and above in my pictures I have the Fc = 250Hz however 1kHz is not at 0dB. To overcome this problem would I need a higher order circuit? so to make the roll off sharper?

Comment: @Pllsz I'd recommend that you go back and carefully re-write your question so that we don't over-think and so that the entire context is carefully delineated. Just a thought.

Comment: Okay, ill try my best.